# Orientation Change problems in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, screen-orientation, glsurfaceview

i am rotating a polygon using Android openGLES1.0 . if i change orientation of the device(Landscape to portrait viceversa) continuously 2,3 times my activity have GLSurfaceView dies.it results to previous Activity(screen).logcat is showing follwing messages.
please help me.

Here is my Log:

```
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28): pid: 860, tid: 878  >>> com.samples.android.MyExample <<<
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 46aff000
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 46aff000  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000268  r3 ffffffff
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000120  r5 46afeec8  r6 000003c0  r7 00000640
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 475fad88  r9 42f26ee4  10 42f26ecc  fp 0011dcf0
09-08 19:39:29.865: INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip ffffffff  sp 475fad1c  lr ffffffff  pc afb043f4  cpsr 20000010
09-08 19:39:30.005: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 000043f4  /system/lib/libcutils.so
09-08 19:39:30.025: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00015284  /system/lib/libpixelflinger.so
09-08 19:39:30.025: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 000153cc  /system/lib/libpixelflinger.so
09-08 19:39:30.025: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc 00014b84  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-08 19:39:30.025: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc 0000f1f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.025: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #05  pc 00037fcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.035: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #06  pc 00031642  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.035: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #07  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.035: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #08  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.035: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #09  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.045: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #10  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.045: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #11  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.055: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #12  pc 00041c78  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-08 19:39:30.055: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #13  pc 00010000  /system/lib/libc.so
09-08 19:39:30.055: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #14  pc 0000fad4  /system/lib/libc.so
09-08 19:39:30.055: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
09-08 19:39:30.055: INFO/DEBUG(28): afb043e4 e1b03103 24801004 e1a03001 e2522020 
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28): afb043f4 28a0500a 28a0500a 2afffffb e2822020 
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28): afb04404 e1b02e02 28a0500a 48a04002 e1b02102 
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28): stack:
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facdc  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475face0  bf8295fb  
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475face4  bf800000  
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475face8  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.065: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facec  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facf0  c0014afd  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facf4  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facf8  40c19648  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475facfc  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad00  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad04  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad08  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad0c  40805851  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad10  df002777  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad14  e3a070ad  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad18  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28): #00 475fad1c  acf15287  /system/lib/libpixelflinger.so
09-08 19:39:30.075: INFO/DEBUG(28): #01 475fad20  bf8295fb  
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad24  0000ffff  [heap]
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad28  00000000  
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad2c  003e8540  [heap]
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad30  000000b3  
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad34  000002d4  
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad38  000001e0  
09-08 19:39:30.085: INFO/DEBUG(28):     475fad3c  acf153d1  /system/lib/libpixelflinger.so
09-08 19:39:31.444: DEBUG/Zygote(30): Process 860 terminated by signal (11)
09-08 19:39:31.454: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Process com.samples.android.MyExample (pid 860) has died.
09-08 19:39:31.465: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{44dbc0b0 com.samples.android.MyExample/com.samples.android.MyExample.polygonActivity paused=false}
09-08 19:39:31.465: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{44ec8d30 com.samples.android.MyExample/com.samples.android.MyExample.polygonsTabActivity paused=false}
09-08 19:39:31.474: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Start proc com.samples.android.MyExample for activity com.samples.android.MyExample/.polygonsTabActivity: pid=879 uid=10028 gids={3003}
09-08 19:39:31.474: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{44e47ee0 SurfaceView paused=false}
09-08 19:39:31.565: DEBUG/ddm-heap(879): Got feature list request
09-08 19:39:31.595: INFO/UsageStats(52): Unexpected resume of com.samples.android.MyExample while already resumed in com.samples.android.MyExample
09-08 19:39:31.725: DEBUG/dalvikvm(879): GC freed 702 objects / 55456 bytes in 46ms
09-08 19:39:31.785: DEBUG/dalvikvm(879): GC freed 73 objects / 2888 bytes in 34ms
09-08 19:39:31.955: WARN/PhoneWindow(879): Previously focused view reported id 16908298 during save, but can't be found during restore.
09-08 19:39:32.075: WARN/InputManagerService(52): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 860 uid 10028
09-08 19:39:32.355: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity com.samples.android.MyExample/.polygonsTabActivity: 897 ms (total 897 ms)
09-08 19:39:33.525: DEBUG/dalvikvm(52): GC freed 1330 objects / 60912 bytes in 73ms
polygon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the orientation change. Depending upon what you are doing though, this may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using view.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true) if you're using API 3+